# .Net WCF Service and Java Client - Handling SOAP Fault

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap, cxf

I am invoking a WCF web-service (SOAP based) using Java client. The client is generated using apache cxf wsdl2java utility.
When the invoked service responds with a fault, I am not able to handle it using catch (javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException), though when I invoke the service using SoapUI I see a valid soap response with fault envelope.
Code Snippet:

```
try{            
iServiceInterface.postDataToSPOnline(USERNAME, PASSWORD,loExpense);             }
        catch(SOAPFaultException soapEx){
            try {
            //Not Invoked
            System.out.println(“SOAPFaultException”);           
        } catch(Exception exp) {            
            //Not Invoked
            System.out.println(“Exception”);
        } finally {
            //Control reaches here post calling the service
            System.out.println(“Finally”); 
        }
```

SoapUI response on invoking the service when fault is returned in response:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
               <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
               <InnerException i:nil="true"/>
               <Message>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</Message>
               <StackTrace>at 
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</StackTrace>
               <Type>System.NullReferenceException</Type>
            </ExceptionDetail>
         </detail>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Would appreciate your suggestions in handling this scenario.

Thanks,
Wajid

Comment: Is possible that your webservice responds a soapfault without setting http-header status as 500 internal server error? You can check it from your soapui response.

Comment: Thanks but that is not the case..                              HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 8098
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 18 Feb 2014 18:15:19 GMT

Comment: The wsdl operation of the service I invoke does not include the fault message. I assume that may be the reason and the Error that is thrown by the client must not fall in the Exception class of java. Thus this behavior.